# Python write text to .tar.gz

Tags: python, python-2.7, tar, logfile

I look for a possibility to write a text file directly (OnTheFly) in a .tar.gz file with python. The best would be a solution like `fobj = open (arg.file, "a")` to append the text.

I want to use this feature for long log files that you are not allowed to split.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how you want to put text directly-`tar.gz` is not a text file.. you want to place `.txt` file in `.tar.gz` archive?

Comment: Excuse the misunderstanding. Yes exactly what I mean. With direct I meant OnTheFly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but most likely not in the way you'd like to use it.

`.tar.gz` is actually two things in one: [`gz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) or [`gzip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) is being used for compression, but this tool can only compress *single files*, so if you want to zip multiple files to a compressed archive, you would need to join these files first. This is what [`tar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) does, it takes multiple files and joins them to an archive.

If you have a single long logfile, just [`gzip`ing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) it would be easier. For this, Python has the [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/gzip.html) module, you can write directly into the compressed file:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('logfile.gz', 'a') as log:
    # Needs to be a bytestring in Python 3
    log.write(b"I'm a log message.\n")
```

If you definitely need to write into a `tar`-archive, you can use Python's [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) module. However, this module does not support *appending* to a file (mode `'a'`), therefore a tarfile might not be the best solution for logging.